# Reduce ODE into 1st order

Tags: differential-equations, replacement, symbolic, undocumented

I have an explicit set of differential equations:

$ \ddot{x}=f(x,\dot{x})$

I would like to reduce it in the following way:

$ \dot{y} = g(y)$

by substitutions as shown here: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Reduction_to_a_first-order_system). I have done this heuristically for a certain system, using rules and `CoefficientArrays`. Yet I would like to have a function that would make up the new family of unknown functions automatically, and get this reduction done in an efficient and clean way -*whatever may be the number of equations*, i.e. the number of unknown functions. 
I don't need it, yet it could be useful to also try and develop a code for a differential equations of higher order.

**Example (2 equations)**

$a_{11} \ddot{x}_1+a_{12} \ddot{x}_2 +b_{11} \dot{x}_1 +b_{12} \dot{x}_2 +c_{11} \dot{x}_1 x_2 +c_{12}x_1 \dot{x}_2+d_{11}x_1+d_{12}x_2+f_1=0  $
$a_{21} \ddot{x}_1+a_{22} \ddot{x}_2 +b_{21} \dot{x}_1 +b_{22} \dot{x}_2 +c_{21} \dot{x}_1 x_2 +c_{22}x_1 \dot{x}_2+d_{21}x_1+d_{22}x_2+f_2=0  $

```
(* Corresponding code *)
f1 = {a11 D[x1[t], {t, 2}] + a12 D[x2[t], {t, 2}] + 
    b11 D[x1[t], {t, 1}] + b12 D[x2[t], {t, 1}] + 
    c11 D[x1[t], {t, 1}] x2[t] + c12 x1[t] D[x2[t], {t, 1}] + 
    d11 x1[t] + d12 x2[t] + ff1, 
   a21 D[x1[t], {t, 2}] + a22 D[x2[t], {t, 2}] + 
    b21 D[x1[t], {t, 1}] + b22 D[x2[t], {t, 1}] + 
    c21 D[x1[t], {t, 1}] x2[t] + c22 x1[t] D[x2[t], {t, 1}] + 
    d21 x1[t] + d22 x2[t] + ff2};
```

We define:

$x_1 =y_1$

$\dot{x}_1=y_2$

$x_2 =y_3$

$\dot{x}_2=y_4$

And obtain the following first order system of equations:

$a_{11} \dot{y}_2+a_{12} \dot{y}_4 +b_{11} y_2 +b_{12} y_4 +c_{11} y_2 y_3 +c_{12}y_1 y_4+d_{11}y_1+d_{12}y_3+f_1=0  $

$a_{21} \dot{y}_2+a_{22} \dot{y}_4 +b_{21} y_2 +b_{22} y_4 +c_{21} y_2 y_3 +c_{22}y_1 y_4+d_{21}y_1+d_{22}y_3+f_2=0$

$\dot{y}_1=y_2$

$\dot{y}_3=y_4$

**UPDATE: Mathematica already has a function for this**

Indeed, I found out this is a duplicate question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91569/convert-de-to-first-order/91577#91577), and that indeed Mathematica already has a function for this. Yet I would like to not delete this having xzczd worked on it and, especially, having received such an interesting answer. I consider his answer a real lesson of coding and thank him again.

Comment: Could you give an example set of equations?

Comment: @Feyre I added an example, thanks for helping.

Comment: I hope you don't mind I put an [tag:undocumented] tag on the question, since my answer explains an undocumented function. (The tag wiki says it's for *questions* about undocumented functions, but I thought it might help people find ``Internal`ProcessEquations`FirstOrderize``, who were searching for something like it.)

Comment: Oh, no @MichaelE2 feel welcome to do this. I think your answer is very useful. I must add that Kuba's answer to the linked question above (use of the function NonlinearStateSpaceModel (or AffineSpaceStateModel), is valid only under the condition of linearizing the highest derivative (or the term regarding, eventually the input). I suppose your approach too, right? I think your answer is particularly valid as it helps getting through this beyond "control" theory.

Comment: "I suppose your approach too, right?" -- I'm not sure if you're asking whether my approach linearizes, but just to be clear, it does not: `firstOrderize[{x1'''[t]^2 == x2'[t] + x1[t], x2''[t]^3 == -x1[t]}, {x1, x2}, t]`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Introduction

I thought I would present a way to leverage built-in functions to do this. I've known for a long time that `NDSolve` sets up an ODE problem as system of first-order equations, so the basic code must be in there.  Apparently, though, it's not easily found.  There is the tantalizingly named `` Internal`ProcessEquations`FirstOrderize ``, which sounds perfect.  It takes 4 to 6 arguments, and eventually I guessed how to set up the OP's problem.

```
fop = Internal`ProcessEquations`FirstOrderize[Thread[f1 == 0], {t}, 1, {x1, x2}]; 
Column[fop, Dividers -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The new system is given by joining the first two components of the output:

```
newsys = Join @@ fop[[1 ;; 2]]
```

The new variables are stored in

```
fop[[3]]
(*  {{x1, NDSolve`x1$56$1}, {x2, NDSolve`x2$84$1}}  *)
```

And the relationship to the original problem is given in the rules in the last component:

```
fop[[4]]
(*  {NDSolve`x1$56$1 -> Derivative[1][x1], NDSolve`x2$84$1 -> Derivative[1][x2]}  *)
```

If you don't like the `` NDSolve` `` module variables, there is another utility that can be discovered via [`state@"VariableTransformation"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#93858351) in the `NDSolve` state data components. There's no documentation, AFAIK, but you can generate examples by evaluating `` NDSolve`StateData `` objects.  Its form is

```
Internal`ProcessEquations`FirstOrderReplace[expr, indepVars, n, depVars, newVars]
```

(I've only ever seen `n == 1` in the third position in an ODE.)  For example, for the OP's system,

```
Internal`ProcessEquations`FirstOrderReplace[
 Thread[f1 == 0], {t}, 1, {x1, x2}, {{X, XP}, {Y,YP}}]
(*
  {ff1 + d11 X[t] + b11 XP[t] + d12 Y[t] + c11 XP[t] Y[t] + b12 YP[t] + 
     c12 X[t] YP[t] + a11 XP'[t] + a12 YP'[t] == 0,
   ff2 + d21 X[t] + b21 XP[t] + d22 Y[t] + c21 XP[t] Y[t] + b22 YP[t] + 
     c22 X[t] YP[t] + a21 XP'[t] + a22 YP'[t] == 0}
*)
```

Note the list of lists in the new variable names. Each instance of `x1` and `x1'` is replaced by `X` and `XP` respectively; `x1''` is replaced by `XP'`. Likewise for the other variable `x2`.

#### General-purpose function

Here is a function that allows renaming of the variables as the OP wishes. It's a bit tricky not to rename the left hand sides with `FirstOrderReplace`; I do it by inactivating `Derivative` temporarily.

```
(* With arbitrary symbol renaming *)
ClearAll[firstOrderize];
Options[firstOrderize] = {"NewSymbolGenerator" -> (Unique["y"] &)};
firstOrderize[sys_, vars_, t_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{fop, newsym, toNewVar},
  newsym = OptionValue["NewSymbolGenerator"];
  fop = Internal`ProcessEquations`FirstOrderize[sys, {t}, 1, vars];
  If[newsym === Automatic,
   (* don't rename *)
   Flatten@ fop[[1 ;; 2]],
   (* rename *)
   toNewVar = With[{newvars = MapIndexed[newsym, fop[[3]], {2}]},
     Internal`ProcessEquations`FirstOrderReplace[#, {t}, 1, vars, newvars] &];
   Flatten@ {toNewVar[fop[[1]] /. Last[fop]],
     Activate[toNewVar[Inactivate[Evaluate@fop[[2]], Derivative]] /. 
       toNewVar[fop[[4]]]]}
   ]
  ]
```

#### Examples

OP's Example: The automatic renaming function uses `Unique["y"]`, which will add a number to `"y"`, whatever number is next.

```
firstOrderize[Thread[f1 == 0], {x1, x2}, t]
(*
  {ff1 + d11 y3[t] + b11 y4[t] + d12 y5[t] + c11 y4[t] y5[t] + 
     b12 y6[t] + c12 y3[t] y6[t] + a11 y4'[t] + a12 y6'[t] == 0, 
   ff2 + d21 y3[t] + b21 y4[t] + d22 y5[t] + c21 y4[t] y5[t] + 
     b22 y6[t] + c22 y3[t] y6[t] + a21 y4'[t] + a22 y6'[t] == 0,
   y3'[t] == y4[t], 
   y5'[t] == y6[t]}
*)
```

One can use the option `"NewSymbolGenerator"` to specify how you want the symbols generated.  It should be a function, which will be applied to the `NDSolve` variables in `fop[[3]]` with `MapIndexed` at level `{2}`.

```
firstOrderize[{x1'[t]^2 == x2'[t] + x1[t], x2''[t] == -x1[t]}, {x1, x2}, t,
 "NewSymbolGenerator" -> (Symbol[{"a", "b"}[[First@#2]] <> ToString@Last@#2] &)]
(*  {a1'[t]^2 == a1[t] + b2[t], b2'[t] == -a1[t], b1'[t] == b2[t]}  *)
```

One way to get numbering from `1` to `4` every time:

```
Module[{n = 0},
 firstOrderize[{x1''[t] == x2[t] + x1[t], x2''[t] == -x1[t]}, {x1, x2}, t,
  "NewSymbolGenerator" -> (Symbol["y" <> ToString[++n]] &)]
 ] // Sort
(*
  {y1'[t] == y2[t],
   y2'[t] == y1[t] + y3[t],
   y3'[t] == y4[t],
   y4'[t] == -y1[t]}
*)
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's my approach, I think it's tidier and more general:

```
ClearAll@to1storder

Options[to1storder] = {"form" -> (#[#2] &), "standardize" -> False};

to1storder[eq_List, func_List, argu_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{maxorder, mapthread, lhsae, lhsde, detoae}, 
  maxorder = #[[First@Ordering[#, -1]]] &@
      Union@Cases[eq, Derivative[i_][#][_] :> i, Infinity] & /@ func;
  mapthread = MapThread[#, {func, maxorder}] &;
  lhsae = mapthread[#[#2]@argu &];
  lhsde = mapthread[#[#2 - 1]'@argu &];
  detoae = ((f : Alternatives @@ func) (i_ : 0) | Derivative[i_][f_])[a_] :> 
    f[i][a];
  {If[OptionValue["standardize"], 
      Solve[#, lhsae] /. Rule -> Equal // Flatten, #] &[
      eq /. detoae] /. Thread[lhsae -> lhsde], 
    mapthread[Table[#[n - 1]'@argu == #[n]@argu, {n, 1, #2 - 1}] &]} /. (f : 
       Alternatives @@ func)[i_] :> OptionValue["form"][f, i]]

to1storder[eq_, func_, argu_, o : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  to1storder[Flatten@{eq}, Flatten@{func}, argu, o];
```

If you want to put the term with highest order of derivative to the left hand side of the equation, set option `"standardize" -> True`.

You may find the definition of `detoae` a little confused. To understand it, just notice that `b /. (n_: 0) b -> n` returns `0`. For more information, check the document of [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html).

The following is an example that your `OrderReduce` can't handle correctly:

```
test = With[{x = x[t], y = y[t]}, {D[x, t, t, t]^2 == -((G m x)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)),
   D[y, t, t] == -((G m y)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))}]

to1storder[test, {x, y}, t, "form" -> Subscript] // Flatten // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: May I ask what does the notatin x[2], y[1] mean?

Comment: @MirkoAveta `x[2]` means `x''`, `y[1]` means `y'` etc., very straight forward :)

Comment: Well then in your output why is there a x[2]'? That would be a second order derivation. The code should output a set of first order differential equations. Is it that I'm misunderstanding your output?

Comment: Also isn't the set of differential equations in your example non-ordinary? I don't think you can actually solve the problem in such a case.

Comment: @MirkoAveta No, `x[_]` is amount to your `Subscript[nvar, _]`, `x[2]` is **corresponding to** the 2nd derivation of `x` in the original equation, but in the new equation set, it's a derivation of nothing. There's no doubt that `test` is an ODE set, though a strange one, you can solve it by e.g. `NDSolve[{test /. {G -> 1, m -> 1}, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 1, x''[0] == 1, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 2}]`

Comment: I'm still not convinced. The output of your `to1storder[]` are the last three equations. Yet why don't the parameters G and m appear in your solution?

Comment: @MirkoAveta No, the output of `to1storder` is all of the 5 equations in the table. The first 2 of them are amount to the $y'_n=F(x,y_1,…,y_n)$ on the wikipedia page, and the last 3 are amount to the rests. If you're still not convinced, just observe the result of `to1storder[f1 == 0//Thread, {x1, x2}, t] // Flatten // TableForm`. (The `f1` is the one in your answer. )

Comment: Ok. I was tricked by the fact that test had a missing ";". ;) Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: Is there a way to change the names of those x[_]? Sorry its just that I feel I'll never get along with them.

Comment: @MirkoAveta Please check my edit.

Comment: You're my hero! I didn't know one could create options!!! This is amazing.

Comment: @xzczd I ran the above code in version 12.1 and got different results.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes Change `i_ : 0` to `(i_ : 0)` fixes the problem. Not sure if this is a bug or intentional change. A new question about this has been posted here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224987/1871 Thx for pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

I have written the following code for this problem. The function reads as inputs the right-hand-side of the equation in implicit form and a list of it's unknown functions explicitly assigning their dependency to the time variable. Any suggestion to make this more tidy or efficient is highly welcomed.

```
    QDim[a_, b_] := TrueQ[Length[a] == Length[b]]
OrderReduce[f__, var__] := With[{}, If[QDim[f, var] == True,
   numbeq = Length[f];
   dimsys = 2 numbeq;
   sysvar = Array[Subscript[nvar, #][t] &, {dimsys}];
   syscom = 
    Flatten@{x, Table[D[var[[i]], {t, 1}], {i, 1, numbeq}], 
      Table[D[var[[i]], {t, 2}], {i, 1, numbeq}]};
   subvar = 
    Flatten@{Table[syscom[[i]] -> sysvar[[i]], {i, 1, dimsys}], 
      Table[D[var[[i]], {t, 2}] -> 
        D[sysvar[[numbeq + i]], {t, 1}], {i, 1, numbeq}], 
      Table[D[var[[i]], {t, 1}] -> sysvar[[numbeq + i]], {i, 1, 
        numbeq}]};
   Flatten@{f /. subvar, 
     Table[D[sysvar[[i]], {t, 1}] - sysvar[[i + numbeq]], {i, 1, 
       numbeq}]}
   , Print["Error: dimensional mismatch."]]]
```

If I apply this to the example above,

```
f1 = {a11 D[x1[t], {t, 2}] + a12 D[x2[t], {t, 2}] + 
    b11 D[x1[t], {t, 1}] + b12 D[x2[t], {t, 1}] + 
    c11 D[x1[t], {t, 1}] x2[t] + c12 x1[t] D[x2[t], {t, 1}] + 
    d11 x1[t] + d12 x2[t] + ff1, 
   a21 D[x1[t], {t, 2}] + a22 D[x2[t], {t, 2}] + 
    b21 D[x1[t], {t, 1}] + b22 D[x2[t], {t, 1}] + 
    c21 D[x1[t], {t, 1}] x2[t] + c22 x1[t] D[x2[t], {t, 1}] + 
    d21 x1[t] + d22 x2[t] + ff2};
OrderReduce[f1, {x1[t], x2[t]}] // TableForm
```

I correctly get:

[image: results]

As I said, any better alternative is highly welcomed!