# Integrating over $x$ in numerically solving a partial integrodifferential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, integral-equations

```
Xmax = 5;

Tmax = 5;

eq1 = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x] + (x - NIntegrate[x u[x, t], {x, 0, Xmax}]) u[x, t]

iv5 = {u[x, 0] == 2/(Sqrt[Pi]*Exp[x^2])};

bcs = {u[0, t] == 2/Sqrt[Pi], u[Xmax, t] == 0};

s10 = NDSolve[ {eq1, iv5, bcs} , {u[x, t] } , {x, 0, Xmax} , {t, 0, Tmax} ];

y = Table[u[x, t] /. s10, {x, 0, Xmax}, {t, 0, Tmax}]

Plot3D[u[x, t] /. s10, {x, 0, Xmax}, {t, 0, Tmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NDSolve` is not capable of solving this sort of problem as a PDE.  Thus, it is necessary to perform the computation by discretizing the PDE in `x`. This procedure is discussed in [Introduction to Method of Lines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html).  A while ago, I solved a somewhat similar problem, [78493](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78564/1063), that involved an integral over `u` in one of the boundary conditions.  Here, the integral of `x u` enters into the PDE itself.  The code nonetheless resembles that in the earlier problem.

```
xmax = 5; tmax = 5;
n = 100; h = xmax/n;
U[t_] = Table[u[i][t], {i, 1, n + 1}];
xtab = Table[(i - 1) h, {i, 1, n + 1}];
```

creates the list of dependent variables and their corresponding positions in `x`.  Then,

```
usum = xtab.U[t] h;
stab = Join[{0}, Thread[(xtab - usum) U[t]][[2 ;; n]], {0}];
```

generates the result of the discretized integral of `x u` and constructs the source term. `(x - NIntegrate[x u[x, t], {x, 0, xmax}]) u[x, t]`.  (Observe that the source term is not applied to the boundary equations.)  Next,

```
eqns = Thread[D[U[t], t] == stab + Join[{0}, ListCorrelate[{1, -2, 1}/h^2, U[t]], {0}]];
initc = Thread[U[0] == 2/(Sqrt[Pi]*Exp[xtab^2])];
lines = NDSolveValue[{eqns, initc}, U[t], {t, 0, tmax}] // Flatten;
```

constructs the coupled ODEs that represent the PDE, the initial conditions, and solves them numerically.  The result is,

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@Thread[{xtab, t, lines}], {t, 0, tmax}, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u"}, BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

**3D Plot**

In response to the comment below, a smooth 3D surface plot can be obtained by

```
Flatten[Table[{(m - 1) h, t, lines[[m]]}, {m, n + 1}, {t, 0, tmax, .1}], 1];
ListPlot3D[%, AxesLabel -> {"x", "t", "u"}, BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

If desired, an `Interpolatingfunction` can be obtained in the same way.

Comment: Can MMA 11 or 12 now solve this form of problem directly?

Comment: @MOON  I do not think so.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hacky way to do it, based on inspecting this:

```
NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eq1, iv5, bcs}, {u[x, t]}, {x, 0, Xmax}, {t, 0, Tmax}]
```

There's a couple of places where you see `MapThread[rhsFN, data, 1]`, that maps the right-hand side of the [first-orderized](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132668/reduce-ode-into-1st-order/132764#132764) differential equation onto the state data.  Since in this case, the RHS is vectorized, we can override `MapThread` and apply the RHS directly with a integration slipped in for a dummy function `int[]`.  Maybe not the safest way to do this, but I thought it was cool enough to share.

```
Xmax = 5;
Tmax = 5;
eq1 = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x, x] + (x - int[u[x, t], x, t]) u[x, t]; (* N.B. *)
iv5 = {u[x, 0] == 2/(Sqrt[Pi]*Exp[x^2])};
bcs = {u[0, t] == 2/Sqrt[Pi], u[Xmax, t] == 0};

Block[{int, xx},
  int[u_, x_, t_ /; t == 0] = (* IC - fools ProcessEquations, thinks int[] a good num.fn. *)
    NIntegrate[2/(Sqrt[Pi]*Exp[x^2]), {x, 0, Xmax}];
  int[u_?VectorQ, x_?VectorQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
    Integrate[Interpolation[Transpose@{x, x*u}][xx], xx] /. xx -> Xmax;
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{MapThread},
   Unprotect[MapThread];
   MapThread[f_, data_, 1] /; ! FreeQ[f, int] := f @@ data;
   Protect[MapThread];
   s10 = NDSolve[{eq1, iv5, bcs}, {u[x, t]}, {x, 0, Xmax}, {t, 0, Tmax}];
   ]];

Plot3D[u[x, t] /. s10, {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Certainly, I am impressed (+1).  Can your method be applied to [192123](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/192123/1063)?  I can solve it by the method I used in the question above, but I have not found the time to write it up yet.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I gave iit a shot.  Since the integral isn't vectorized/listable, I had to adjust some things. Also `MapThread` got used in `ProcessEquations` and my overload of it interfered with that stage..

Comment: @MichaelE2 For a slight extension, if we have 2 integrals, say, `int1[u[x, t], x, t]` and `int2[D[u[x,t],{x,2}], x, t]`, is it correct to use `MapThread[f_, data_, 1] /; ! FreeQ[f, int1] := f @@ data; MapThread[f_, data_, 1] /; ! FreeQ[f, int2] := f @@ data;` to slip both of them in?

Comment: @user55777 You shouldn't have to change anything except `int` to `int1` (or `int2` or `int1 | int2`). Substitute `MapThread[f_, data_, 1] /; ! FreeQ[f, int] := Return[f, NDSolve]` in my example above (and omit the `Plot`). Then `s10` will be set to what `f` (= `rhsFN`) is.  In your case, `rhsFN` should contain both `int1` and `int2`. Now, one limitation is that the `rhsFN` must evaluate correctly when fed a vector of `x` values instead of being mapped over each individual one.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Among others, I don't under the use of `Return`. In the documentation, it only takes one argument (i.e., `Return[expr]`), which is used to return the value of `expr` from a function...

Comment: @user55777 `Return[expr, func]` returns `expr` from `func`, at the first instance of `func` up the `Stack[]`.  I learned about it on this site, I think, from a comment which I can't find.  It's mentioned [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29354/4999) and in the long comment discussion below the answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 If the NDSolve process was split up, should it still be `MapThread[f_, data_, 1] /; ! FreeQ[f, int1|int2] := Return[f, NDSolve]`?

Comment: @user55777  `MapThread[f_, data_, 1] /; ! FreeQ[f, int1|int2] := Return[f, NDSolve]` is just a debugging tool, so that you can see what `f` is.  I used that knowledge to construct the solution above. I thought you could use that information to adapt the answer to the case where there are two `int[]`'s.

Comment: @user55777 Great! And you're welcome.