# Analyzing MethodOfLines

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, interpolation, finite-element-method, mesh

In this example the wave equation

```
U = NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}],
u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0, (* RBn *)
u[x, 0] == 1 - Abs[2 x - 1], (D[u[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0 (* 
ABn *)
}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 },
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> 
{"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.3}}}]
Plot3D[ U[x, t] , {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, Mesh -> All,AxesLabel -> {x, t}]
```

[image]

is solved with the "MethodOfLines" and "FiniteElement".

**My questions**

**#1** How can I get the complete mesh(two dimensional), which NDSolve uses? `U["ElementMesh"["Wireframe" ]` seems to be onedimensional?

**#2** How can I get the time grid of "MethodOfLines"?

**#3** Is it possible to expand the pde with an additional variable to a DAE system and calculate for example `NIntegrate[u[x,t],{x,0,1}]`in every time step t?

Thanks!

**answers #1:**  `xi = Union@Flatten[Map[Union@#[[All, 1]] &, U["Grid"]] , 1] ;`

**answers #2:**  `ti=U["Coordinates"] [[-1]];`

Comment: by "complete mesh(two dimensional)" do you mean a `List` of `TriangleElements` ?

Comment: Yes, elements or node coordinates!

Comment: The problem is that in your example the finite element method is used only for the temporal variable x. The resolution over the time t is done with the "method of line" (which considers the equations as a set of ODEs). Hence from the Finite Element Method point of view, the problem is a 1D problem. That's the reason why the Finite Element Method returns some 'LineElement' and not 'TriangleElement'. By the way, the mesh we see in your question has nothing to do with the real mesh internaly used by the FEM (it's a mesh created by `Plot3D`)

Comment: @andre: Thank you for your helpful answer, which solves my first question.

Comment: I think that `U["ValuesOnGrid"] ` is what you are looking for in the first 2 questions (?)

Comment: Concerning the third one, I have no answer.

Comment: There is `U["Grid"] ` too

Comment: @andre:    `U["Coordinates"] [[-1]]` answers my second question. Thanks for your proposals I didn't know before.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, have you considered self answering the question? Maybe useful to others.

Comment: @ user21 Yes, but 'til now I'm far away from answering my third question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments/OP (for completeness):

> **answers #1:**  `xi = Union@Flatten[Map[Union@#[[All, 1]] &, U["Grid"]] , 1] ;`
>
> **answers #2:**  `ti=U["Coordinates"] [[-1]];`

**answers #3:**

I don't think computing the integrals after `NDSolve[]` would be any less efficient than computing them during.  It's probably possible to do it during the `NDSolve` integration (I've done it before here on the site with the method of lines and a tensor grid, [(192707)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/192707), [(192736)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/192736)), but it's much simpler after `NSolve` has finished.

```
{xmesh, tgrid} = U["Coordinates"];
ivals = Table[NIntegrate[U[x, t], {x} \[Element] xmesh], {t, tgrid}];
ListLinePlot[ivals]
```

[image]

Comment: @ MichaelE2 Thanks, very helpful links!