# NDSolve:Coupled PDE's, initial-boundary value problem: unreasonable "insufficient number of boundary conditions" error

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, nonlinear, boundary-conditions

I tried to NDSolve the PDE system: 
$$\partial_t y = x\partial_z w \quad\quad \partial_t w =  \partial_z y \quad \quad \partial_z x=w $$
for $$(t,z)\in[0,1]\times[-1,0]$$
 with initial conditions
 $$x(0,z)=x_0(z)\quad\quad w(0,z)=-sin^2(z\pi)\quad\quad y(0,z)=1$$
where $x_0(z)$ is the solution of 
$$x_0'(z)=w(0,z)\quad\quad x_0(0)=0$$
and boundary conditions 
$$   x(t,0)=0 \quad\quad w(t,0)=w(t,-1)=0 $$

From a mathematical point of view the initial and boundary conditions provided above are sufficient.

However mathematica warns that "an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified" and as a result "Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution".

So there must be something wrong with my code

```
(*Constructing initial conditions*)
wo[z_] := -Sin[z*π]^2
yo[z_] := 1
s = NDSolve[{x'[z] == wo[z], x[0] == 0}, {x}, {z, 0, -1}] 
xo[z_] := First[x[z] /. s]


(*Evolution of initial conditions towards t=1*)
equations := {D[yt[t, z], t] == xt[t,z]*D[wt[t, z], z], 
  D[wt[t, z], t] == D[yt[t, z], z], 
  D[xt[t, z], z] == wt[t, z], wt[0, z] == wo[z], yt[0, z] == yo[z], 
  wt[t, 0] == 0, wt[t, -1] == 0, xt[t, 0] == 0, xt[0, z] == xo[z]}
system = NDSolve[equations, {wt , yt, xt}, {z, 0, -1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

I get three errors (`NDSolve::pdord`, `NDSolve::bcart`, `NDSolve::ndcf`), the second being  "insufficient number of boundary conditions," but
I cannot see what went wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome. What about a boundary condition for `yt`? Also you may want to look at the DAE tutorial. Perhaps you can find an idea there, not sure though.

Comment: On the boundary $w(t,0)=0$ so $\partial_t w(t,0) = 0$ which leads to $\partial_z y(t,0)=0$. Numerically this means $y(t,0)=y(t,-\Delta x)$ where  $\Delta x$ is the z-grid spacing. So an additional boundary condition would overdetermine the problem.

Comment: Version 11.3.0 produces "NDSolve::pdord: Some of the functions have zero differential order, so the equations will be solved as a system of differential-algebraic equations." and "NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable z. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution. " and " NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable z. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution."

Comment: I agree that `yt` should not need a boundary condition in `z`.  However, it is possible that Mathematica is confused by this problem and, therefore, is incorrectly asking for the boundary condition.  I would try decomposing the PDEs into coupled sets of ODEs in `t` and solving the resulting third-order system.  See the introduction to https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html.  As an aside, you will obtain better accuracy by solving for `xo` using `DSolveValue` instead of `NDSolve`.  Finally, it is better not to use `SetDelayed` when `Set` will do.

Comment: To continue, searching for "user:1063 do-it-yourself" will provide three examples of how to decompose PDEs into ODEs using Mathematica.  I am sure that there are other examples as well on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This computation resembles that in [question 175080](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175178/1063), in that the PDEs include spatial integrals over a dependent variable.  `NDSolve` is not capable of solving this sort of problem as PDEs. Thus, it is necessary to perform the computation by discretizing the PDE in `z`, as outlined in [Introduction to Method of Lines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html). Begin by specifying the initial conditions for `w` and `y`.  (`x` is a matrix of `w` values and does not require an initial condition.)

```
w0[z_] = -Sin[z*Pi]^2;
y0[z_] = 1;
```

Next define the arrays in `z` for the discretized `w` and `y`.

```
zmin = -1; tmax = 1;
n = 100; h = -zmin/n;
W[t_] = Table[w[i][t], {i, n + 1}];
Y[t_] = Table[y[i][t], {i, n}];
```

Note that `w` and `y` are interleaved in `z` to simplify spatial derivatives.  `x`, on  the other hand, is defined symbolically as a function of `w`.

```
wave = ListCorrelate[{1, 1} h/2, W[t]];
X[t_] = Table[-Total[wave[[i ;; n]]], {i, 1, n + 1}];
```

(`x` is collocated with `w`.)  The discretized PDEs and their initial conditions are, then,

```
eqw = Thread[D[W[t], t] == Join[{0}, ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}/h, Y[t]], {0}]];
eqy = Thread[D[Y[t], t] == ListCorrelate[{1, 1}/2, X[t]] ListCorrelate[{-1, 1}/h, 
    W[t]]];
initw = Thread[W[0] == Table[w0[(i - 1) h - 1], {i, n + 1}]];
inity = Thread[Y[0] == Table[y0[(i - 1/2) h - 1], {i, n}]];
```

`NDSolve` handles this large set of coupled ODEs without difficulty:

```
lines = NDSolveValue[{eqw, eqy, initw, inity}, {W[t], Y[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}],
```

and the results can be plotted by

```
wtab = Table[(i - 1) h - 1, {i, 1, n + 1}];
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@Thread[{wtab, t, lines[[1]]}], {t, 0, tmax},
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "w"}, BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
ytab = Table[(i - 1/2) h - 1, {i, 1, n}];
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@Thread[{ytab, t, lines[[2]]}], {t, 0, tmax},
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "y"}, BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why  `Y[t_] = Table[y[i][t], {i, n}];`  is used instead of  `Y[t_] = Table[y[i][t], {i, n+1}];`?

Comment: Also I need some help with the command `X[t_] = Table[-Total[wave[[i ;; n]]], {i, 1, n + 1}];`

Comment: @user61386  `W` and `X` are defined at the cell edges in `z`, so there are `n + 1` of them.  `Y` are defined at cell centers to improve accuracy of numerical derivatives in `z`, so there are `n` of them.  `X` is equal to the integral from `z == 0` to the cell edge for `X`, determined according to the trapezoidal rule.

Answer (score 5):

There is no time-derivative of `xt[t, z]`, which is the source of the errors (this one `NDSolve::pdord` being the principal one, and the other `NDSolve::bcart` cited by the OP apparently being a consequence of it).  Differentiate the `xt[]` equation with respect to `t` and we can get @bbgodfrey's solution.

```
(*Evolution of initial conditions towards t=1*)
equations = {
   D[yt[t, z], t] == xt[t, z]*D[wt[t, z], z],
   D[wt[t, z], t] == D[yt[t, z], z],
   D[D[xt[t, z], z] == wt[t, z], t],    (* differentiate xt[] equation *)
   wt[0, z] == wo[z], wt[t, 0] == 0, wt[t, -1] == 0,
   yt[0, z] == yo[z],
   xt[0, z] == xo[z], xt[t, 0] == 0};
system = NDSolve[equations,
  {wt, yt, xt}, {z, 0, -1}, {t, 0, 1},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 100, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}, 
  MaxStepSize -> {0.01, 1}]  (* an upper bound on the time step size helps *)
```

Visualization:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate@
  Thread[{wt["Coordinates"] /. First@system // Last, t, 
     wt[t, wt["Coordinates"] /. First@system // Last]} /. 
    First@system], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "w"}, BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate@
  Thread[{yt["Coordinates"] /. First@system // Last, t, 
     yt[t, yt["Coordinates"] /. First@system // Last]} /. 
    First@system], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "w"}, BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

[image]

The above elicits an error:

> NDSolve::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate...

This doesn't happen with @bbgodfrey's code, because the system is solved as a system of ODEs and not PDEs: no spatial error estimate is performed.  The error can be eliminated by reducing both the spatial and time step size:

```
system = NDSolve[equations,
  {wt, yt, xt}, {z, 0, -1}, {t, 0, 1},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}, MaxStepSize -> 0.0025]
```

Comment: Very creative (+1).