# Solving system of coupled PDEs with method of lines

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve:

$\partial _{z} U(z,t) = i \sqrt{d} P(z,t)$

$\partial _{t} P(z,t) = -P(z, t) + i \sqrt{d} U(z,t) + i \Omega_{c}(t)S(z, t)$

$\partial _{t} S(z,t) = i \Omega_{c}(t)P(z, t)$

For the initial conditions

$P(z, 0) = 0$

$S(z, 0) = 0$

$U(0, t) = A \exp\Bigg(-4 \ln(2) \Bigg(\frac{t-t_{0}}{\tau}\Bigg)\Bigg) \,,$

where A, $\tau$ and d are all constants.

As I understand it, NDSolve cannot deal with this problem due to there being a derivative of only one dimension on each of the equations.  I've attempted to solve using the method of lines, as shown in answers such as this: [NDSolve:Coupled PDE's, initial-boundary value problem: unreasonable "insufficient number of boundary conditions" error](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186762/ndsolvecoupled-pdes-initial-boundary-value-problem-unreasonable-insufficien?noredirect=1&lq=1&newreg=acb4d7cfe68f49f7b372e5a0d4e5f9c4).  However while the solver shows no errors, plotting the result just produces a blank box.

My code is shown below.  I have removed the part which computes the constants to make it more legible. Capital "I" below refers to the complex number i.

```
d = 84.9601
tau = 0.1
OmegaC = 27.7259


pulseTime = 2 Pi/OmegaC
storageTime = 0.2;
twriteon = t0 - pulseTime/2;
twriteoff = t0 + pulseTime/2;
treadon = t0 + pulseTime/2 + storageTime;
treadoff = t0 + pulseTime/2 + storageTime + pulseTime;
Clear[OmegaFunc]
OmegaFunc[t_?NumericQ /; t < twriteon] = 0;
OmegaFunc[t_?NumericQ /; twriteoff >= t >= twriteon] = OmegaC;
OmegaFunc[t_?NumericQ /; treadon > t > twriteoff] = 0;
OmegaFunc[t_?NumericQ /; treadoff >= t >= treadon] = OmegaC;
OmegaFunc[t_?NumericQ /; t > treadoff] = 0;

(*Plot[OmegaFunc[t], {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> All]*)

(*Initial conditions*)
p0 [z_] = 0;
s0[z_] = 0;
A = 9.39437
u0[t_] = A* Exp[-4*Log[2]*((t - t0 )/tau)^2];
(*Plot[u0[t], {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> All]*)

(*Define arrays in z to discretize problem in z*)
zmax = 1;
n = 4;
h = zmax/n;
P[t_] = Table[p[i][t], {i, 1, n}];
S[t_] = Table[s[i][t], {i, 1, n}];
integrateP = Join[{p[1][t]}, Table[p[i - 2][t] + p[i - 1][t], {i, 3, n}]];
U[t_] = Join[{u0[t]}, integrateP];

(*Construct equations*)
eqP = Thread[
   D[P[t], t] == -P[t] + I Sqrt[d] U[t] + I OmegaFunc[t] S[t]];
eqS = Thread[D[S[t], t] == I OmegaFunc[t] P[t]];
initP = Thread[P[0] == Table[p0[(i - 1) h], {i, 1, n}]];
initS = Thread[S[0] == Table[s0[(i - 1) h], {i, 1, n}]];

(*Solve*)
lines = NDSolve[{eqP, eqS, initP, initS}, {P[t], S[t]}, {t, 0, tend}];

(*Plot*)
ztab = Table[(i - 1) h, {i, 1, n}];
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate@Thread[{ztab, t, lines[[1, 1]]}], {t, 0, tend}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "P"}, 
 BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate@Thread[{ztab, t, lines[[1, 2]]}], {t, 0, tend}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "S"}, 
 BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, Medium}]
```

I've shown the result of plotting P(z, t) below.  S(z, t) is the same.

[image: 1]

Could anyone help with what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: z is over the range [0, 1] and t is [0, 1.4]

Answer (score 2):

We can use first order approximation on `z` as follows

```
d = 84.9601;
tau = 0.1; t0 = .1;
OmegaC = 27.7259;


pulseTime = 2 Pi/OmegaC;
storageTime = 0.2;
twriteon = t0 - pulseTime/2;
twriteoff = t0 + pulseTime/2;
treadon = t0 + pulseTime/2 + storageTime;
treadoff = t0 + pulseTime/2 + storageTime + pulseTime;
Clear[OmegaFunc]
OmegaFunc[t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{0, t < twriteon}, {OmegaC, 
    twriteoff >= t >= twriteon}, {0, 
    treadon > t > twriteoff}, {OmegaC, treadoff >= t >= treadon}, {0, 
    t > treadoff}}]


(*Plot[OmegaFunc[t],{t,0,tend},PlotRange\[Rule]All]*)

(*Initial conditions*)
p0[z_] = 0;
s0[z_] = 0;
A = 9.39437;
u0[t_] = A*Exp[-4*Log[2]*((t - t0)/tau)^2];
(*Plot[u0[t],{t,0,tend},PlotRange\[Rule]All]*)

(*Define arrays in z to discretize problem in z*)
zmax = 1;
n = 41;
h = zmax/n;
P[t_] = Table[p[i][t], {i, 1, n}];
S[t_] = Table[s[i][t], {i, 1, n}];



(*Construct equations*)
eqP = Table[
   D[p[i][t], t] == -p[i][t] + 
     I Sqrt[d] (u0[t] + h Sum[p[j][t], {j, 1, i}]) + 
     I OmegaFunc[t] s[i][t], {i, n}];
eqS = Table[D[s[i][t], t] == I OmegaFunc[t] p[i][t], {i, n}];
initP = Table[p[i][0] == 0, {i, 1, n}];
initS = Table[s[i][0] == 0, {i, 1, n}];

(*Solve*)

tend = 1.4; var = 
 Join[Table[p[i], {i, n}], Table[s[i], {i, n}]]; sols = 
 NDSolve[{eqP, eqS, initP, initS}, var, {t, 0, tend}];

(*Plot*)
```

Since functions `P, S, U` are complex we can visualize `Re`,`Im`, `Abs` as

```
ztab = Table[(i - 1) h, {i, 1, n}]; U = 
 Join[{u0[t]}, h Table[Sum[p[j][t], {j, i}], {i, n}]];
lst1 = Flatten[
   Table[{ztab[[i]], t, Re[p[i][t]] /. First[sols]}, {i, n}, {t, 0, 
     tend, .01 tend}], 1];
lst2 = Flatten[
  Table[{ztab[[i]], t, Re[s[i][t]] /. First[sols]}, {i, n}, {t, 0, 
    tend}], 1]; lst3 = 
 Flatten[Table[{ztab[[i]], t, Re[U[[i]]] /. First[sols]}, {i, n}, {t, 
    0, tend}], 1];

{ListPlot3D[lst1, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "P"}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None], 
 ListPlot3D[lst2, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "S"}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None], 
 ListPlot3D[lst3, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "U"}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None]}

lst11 = Flatten[
   Table[{ztab[[i]], t, Im[p[i][t]] /. First[sols]}, {i, n}, {t, 0, 
     tend, .01 tend}], 1];
lst21 = Flatten[
  Table[{ztab[[i]], t, Im[s[i][t]] /. First[sols]}, {i, n}, {t, 0, 
    tend}], 1]; lst31 = 
 Flatten[Table[{ztab[[i]], t, Im[U[[i]]] /. First[sols]}, {i, n}, {t, 
    0, tend}], 1]; {ListPlot3D[lst11, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "P"}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None], 
 ListPlot3D[lst21, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "S"}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None], 
 ListPlot3D[lst31, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "U"}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None]}

lst12 = Flatten[
   Table[{ztab[[i]], t, Abs[p[i][t]] /. First[sols]}, {i, n}, {t, 0, 
     tend, .01 tend}], 1];
lst22 = Flatten[
  Table[{ztab[[i]], t, Abs[s[i][t]] /. First[sols]}, {i, n}, {t, 0, 
    tend}], 1]; lst32 = 
 Flatten[Table[{ztab[[i]], t, Im[U[[i]]] /. First[sols]}, {i, n}, {t, 
    0, tend}], 1]; {ListPlot3D[lst12, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "|P|"}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None], 
 ListPlot3D[lst22, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "|S|"}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None], 
 ListPlot3D[lst32, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "t", "|U|"}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None]}
```

[image: Figure 1]