# Numerical solution of integro-differential equation where the integral term contains a double integral

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I have the following code:

```
sys = {
    D[f[ϵ, x], {x, 2}] + Iee[ϵ, x] + Iph[ϵ, x] == 0,  
    f[ϵ, -L/2] == fF[ϵ - eV/2], 
    f[ϵ, L/2] == fF[ϵ + eV/2]
}
where:
Iee[ϵ_, x_] := a Integrate[
    Integrate[
        (f[ϵ, x] f[ϵ1 - ω, x] (1 - f[ϵ - ω, x]) (1 - f[ϵ1, x]) - 
         f[ϵ - ω, x] f[ϵ1, x] (1 - f[ϵ, x]) (1 - f[ϵ1 - ω, x])), 
        {ϵ1, -∞, ∞}, 
        {ω, -∞, ∞}
    ]
]

Iph[ϵ_, x_] := b Integrate[
    ω^2 ((1 - f[ϵ, x]) f[ϵ + ω, x] (1 + n[ω]) + 
         (1 - f[ϵ, x]) f[ϵ - ω] n[ω] - 
         f[ϵ, x] (1 - f[ϵ - ω]) (1 + n[ω]) - 
         f[ϵ, x] (1 - f[ϵ + ω]) n[ω]), 
    {ω, 0, ∞}
]
n[ω_] = 1/(Exp[ω/T] - 1);
fF[ϵ_] = 1/(1 + Exp[ϵ/T]);
```

where `a,b,T,L,eV` are
constants.

I need to solve this equation numerically. As I understand, simple functions as well as
`NDSolve` don't work here, and I need to use The
Numerical Method of Lines (like here [Integrating over $x$ in numerically solving a partial integrodifferential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175080/integrating-over-x-in-numerically-solving-a-partial-integrodifferential-equati?noredirect=1&lq=1))

But anyway I still dont understand what to do with limits of integration and how to connect it with my boundary conditions.

Comment: For a numerical solution it would be helpful to find finite integration limits. I don't know the parameter values Do you think it's possible to find an appropriate transformation `w,ϵ`?

Comment: As the first step towards a numerical solution, it would be necessary to determine the parameters `a,b,T, L, eV`.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Im not sure, but i gonna try to use something like 2 last functions for such transform. It might be naturally in this contecst.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I thought that its possible to solve for all real. For the first solution it should be ok use any non zero constants.

Comment: @PabloEscobar In `Iph` definition there are `f[ϵ, x]` and `f[ϵ - ω]`. Is it a typo?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, no, the argument of the function is represented by the difference.

Comment: @PabloEscobar Please pay attention that `f[ϵ, x]` is a function of two variables, while `f[ϵ - ω]` is a function of one variable. Therefore, use `f[ϵ - ω, x]` instead of `f[ϵ - ω]`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Whoopps, yes, it should be f[ϵ - ω,x]